# Search method doesn't work with Autodesk Navisworks file in Autodesk forge Viewer API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

Search method always return empty objects with Navisworks file but it works with Revit file. Here is the sample code which works with revit file but doesn't work with navisworks file.

```
viewer.search('Levels', function(dbIds){ console.log(dbIds); }, null, ['Type'])
```

Please let me know if you have a solution for .nwd file

Comment: It is probably because no component is matching the search. Navisworks and Revit file hierarchy and properties are different after extraction on Forge. The viewer.search method is looking for component property values that are matching your search, did you make sure that any component have the property value you are looking for? Did you test with another value that you know belongs to at least one component?

Comment: @PhilippeLeefsma, I tried with few properties but couldn't get desire result.

Comment: adding to this, in this case you're searching for `Levels` on the `Type` attribute, is that available on your Navisworks file? Note that each NW file can have different attributes depending on which files were used to create it.

Comment: Yes @AugustoGoncalves, I have verified the properties using meta data api.